# Remodeling, do I need to add fire blocking

Tags: framing, code-compliance, remodeling

I am in the process of remodeling a bathroom built in 1961.  One thing I noticed is that non of the walls I have opened up have any fire blocking in them.  I am only going to have an electrical and plumbing inspection as part of this project do I need to bring the framing up to code as well?

[image: opened walls]

This will be easy in the wall on the right but I would like to avoid disturbing the outside wall and insulation if I could.  I also have a couple of pocket doors to contend with, or can I just ignore those?

Comment: What state are you in? Assuming you are in the United States. It's better to just quote directly from the relevant Code your state/jurisdiction uses where possible. Also, how high is that wall? 8ft?

Comment: Regardless of fire blocking (which can be placed to serve double-duty) put in lumber to anchor grab bars if ever needed and document the positions, now, while the walls are open and it's *easy!*

Comment: @TylerH I am in semi-rural Minnesota, the nearest city handles our building permits althought we are not in city limits.  The ceiling is 8 foot.  There was a wall mounted toilet in that area so part of that is framed out an extra 2 inches and there are some extra studs

Comment: Typically by the IRC which is what I think is what's relevant here, you don't need fire blocking in walls under 10ft except at each floor and ceiling (which are built-in via the bottom and top plates already), but it's been a while since I looked at it so I'll let someone else provide an actual answer with citations.